Did Jerry Lucas memorize 50+ pages of a phone book?
NBA.com writes about NBA player and author Jerry Lucas:

He could memorize 50 pages of the New York City phone book in one sitting. ... At a party co-hosted by teammate Bill Bradley and the writer Dick Schaap, Lucas demonstrated the trick for chess champion Bobby Fischer, who was awestruck. After retiring in 1974, Lucas went on to a lucrative sideline as a TV personality and guest speaker. In his second career, he’s known as “Dr. Memory.”

WCHS's Mark Martin quoted Jerry Lucas as saying:

"I memorized 200 pages in the Manhattan phone book and demonstrated it various times on television shows," Lucas said. "I memorized 100 page magazines, many, many of them, to demonstrate on television programs that I would appear. As a guest on television programs, I would meet maybe 300 or 400 people who were going to be in the studio audience before the program began. And then when I came on the program, I'd have them all stand up and point to and name all their last names.

This TV interview shows him with formidable, albeit imperfect memory skills.  I didn't find him demonstrate phone-book memorization skills.
Question: Did Jerry Lucas memorize 50+ pages of a phone book?

I don't know anything about Jerry Lucas specifically, but there are a number of techniques that various people have used for some pretty incredible sounding feats or memorization, here is an example of 100.000 digits of pi (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_Haraguchi) which doesn't sound that different to 50 pages of a phone book to me.

There were some articles mentioning that Jerry Lucas has photographic memory, but reading his Wikipedia article on memorization, probably that's not the case.

in one sitting is probably false, unless that "one sitting" was at least 10s of hours. NYT (1972): Jerry Lucas stuffed the Manhattan telephone book into his bag for road trips during the regular season. Not the whole book, though. Only the first 500 of its 1,884 pages. He is memorizing names and corresponding telephone numbers, those 500 pages.  It's not so incredible if he took many days/weeks/months to memorize 50 pages.
